# @autowire not creating object with custom annotation in junit

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, annotations

I am new to spring boot and I am writing Junit for my REST Api.so many annotation are required by my class to run Junit. So I planned to put all annotation in one custom annotation and use that custom annotation in my Junit class. But now my Autowire is stopped working.

> I tried to create custom annotation and used that in my Junit class
>   but now @Autowire annotation has stopped to work.

*Below is code of custom annotation:*

```
@Inherited

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)

@Documented

@Category(UnitTest.class)

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = {AptDataApiApplicationRepo.class })

@TestPropertySource("classpath:application-test.properties")

public @interface RepoTestConfig {

}
```

// My JUnit class code

```
@RepoTestConfig

public class HolidayRepoTest {

    @Autowired
    private IHolidayRepo iHolidayRepo;
}
```

// here spring throwing an exception when spring context is trying to get up

Exception coming is :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.demo.repository.IHolidayRepo' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

@Note: When I am putting all annotation in HolidayRepoTest class then every thing is fine.

Comment: Read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html. You need to use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html.

Comment: @JBNizet, I Have tried both RETENTION policies CLASS and RUNTIME, But no success.

Comment: I don't think @RunWith(SpringRunner.class) (and Category) can be part of a meta annotation. It's not a Spring annotation. It's a JUnit one.

Comment: @JBNizet,thanks It working now.after moving both to my Junit class

Comment: JUnit 5 supports meta-annotations so your approach will work in the future should you upgrade from JUnit 4.